# How to calculate the weighted sum within a sliding window?

Tags: moving-average, dolphindb

I want to calculate the moving sum of a sequence X_i, with [1,2,3,4] as weights, i.e, calculating X_i + 2*X_(i-1) + 3 * X_(i-2) + 4 * X_(i-3).

I tried the following functions：

(1) `mwsum`: The X and Y (weights) parameter of function mwsum must be of equal size, whereas I want to specify weights which is of equal size to window.

(2)`mavg`: A NaN value may be returned when the weighted sum is 0.

Neither of two approaches can meet the demand. So how can I perform such calculations?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following script:

```
x + 2 * move(x,1) + 3 * move(x,2) + 4 * move(x,3)
```